# For the Quorum and Convention badges, what are posts?

Tags: discussion, badges

The descriptions of the Quorum and Convention badges refer to posts. Is a post a question, an answer, or either?

Comment: As an aside, this post qualifies, now that it has score 2.

Comment: Congrats on your [shiny new Quorum badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/900/quorum?userid=604687)!

Comment: Aww, you guys! <3

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, a post is either a question or an answer.

So for the Quorum badge, just one question *or* one answer with score 2 or up will do.

For the Convention badge, you need 10 posts; that can be 10 questions, 10 answers, or any combination of the two, as long as they have a score of 2 or higher.

Also see the [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms):

> #### Post
>
> Refers to either a question or an answer.

Comment: Man, quit proving you're a good mod. We get it already!

Answer (score 3):

Post is either a question or answer.